# Filter pandas dataframe - Top and Bottom N rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with dates and values.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['11-10','11-10','11-10','12-10','12-10','12-10'],
                   'id': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
                   'val':[20, 30, 40, 50, 25, 35] })
```

I'd like the filter the DataFrame to only include top and bottom N rows for each date. Let's say N = 2. Then, the dataframe would discard the 1st row `11-10 20` and 5th row `12-10 25`.

Hoping for a solution that can scale for different values of `N`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the dataframe by `date` then call `nlargest` for `val` column, passing the value of `N`:

```py
>>> df.groupby('date')['val'].nlargest(2)
date    
11-10  2    40
       1    30
12-10  3    50
       5    35
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

If needed, you can call `to_frame()` on the resulting Series to convert it to a dataframe.

For the updated question, you can still implement the above code with some additional works to get the ids as well, then inner merge with the original dataframe:

```py
out= (df.set_index('id')
        .groupby(['date'])['val']
        .nlargest(2)
        .to_frame('val')
        .reset_index()
        .merge(df, how='inner')
      )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
    date  id  val
0  11-10   2   40
1  11-10   1   30
2  12-10   1   50
3  12-10   2   35
```

Comment: I'd like to retain the columns in groupby though. When I run this I get only the series.

Comment: That's why I have mentioned that you can additionally call `to_frame` to convert it to the dataframe, and even pass the column name: `df.groupby('date')['val'].nlargest(2).to_frame('val')`

Comment: I obtain a dataframe with on column only, `val`. The columns used in groupby are lost. I'd like to retain them.

Comment: You mean you have extra columns as well?

Comment: Yes, I have two columns in `groupby`. Sorry, this is a mock df posted on SO.

Comment: @kms, see the updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to sort the columns and take the tail on the groupby:

```py
(df.sort_values(['date', 'val'])
   .groupby('date', sort = False)
   .tail(n=2)
)
    date  id  val
1  11-10   1   30
2  11-10   2   40
5  12-10   2   35
3  12-10   1   50
```